# Editing .doc document using AppleScript

Tags: batch-file, automation, click, applescript, save

I am trying to batch convert some .doc files to .pdf
I am pretty sure I've got the concept right, I just do not know how to reference the format to change the file format when I "Save As"

set F to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
 set P to (files of entire contents of F)
 repeat with I from 1 to number of items in P
  set this_item to item I of P as alias
  tell application "Microsoft Word"
   activate
   open this_item
   save as active document file format format PDF
   close window 1
  end tell
 end repeat
end tell

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A little google searching would have turned up [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2009/mar/msg00028.html)...

which is basically the whole script you're trying to write.